# how to link process output to textview and automatically update in realtime?

Tags: android, multithreading, textview, handler, tcpdump

I'm not the best programmer, actually, I'm pretty bad :(
I need help with something thats driving my crazy. basically I have a tcpdump process, I want to extract the output and put it into a textview which is updated every few milliseconds, I've tried everything and just cant get it to work.

I don't get any errors and it seems to work in the background, but only displays chunks of text only after I go to the homescreen and return back into the app. however, it doesnt constantly update the textview, and sometimes hangs and crashes.

I've created a simple handler which can update the textview with plain text without problems, but then i faced major problems getting it to read the process.

**Begin button**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.capture);

    this.LiveTraffic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LiveTraffic);
    this.CaptureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CaptureText);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.ipv4)).setText(getLocalIpv4Address());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.ipv6)).setText(getLocalIpv6Address());


    //Begin button              
    final Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now Capturing Packets", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {

                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes("/data/local/tcpdump -q\n");
                os.flush();
                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                inputStream = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());

                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps tcpdump");

                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(process2.getInputStream());
                String temp = in.readLine();
                temp = in.readLine();
                temp = temp.replaceAll("^root *([0-9]*).*", "$1");
                pid = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                Log.e("MyTemp", "" + pid);
                process2.destroy();

                CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.CaptureText.setText("Active");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            ListenThread thread = new ListenThread(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)));
            thread.start();
        }
    });
}
```

**ListenThread class**

```
public class ListenThread extends Thread {

    public ListenThread(BufferedReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }
    private BufferedReader reader = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        while (true) {
            try {
                CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.CaptureText.setText("exec");
                int a = 1;
                String received = reader.readLine();
                while (a == 1) {
                    CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.LiveTraffic.append(received);
                    CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.LiveTraffic.append("\n");
                    received = reader.readLine();
                    CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.CaptureText.setText("in loop");

                }
                CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.CaptureText.setText("out loop");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("FSE", "", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I've tried everything and just cant get it to work": you need to be more specific about what does not work. Do you get an error? Which one? Does it not behave as expected? etc.

Comment: no errors, it seems to work in the background, but only displays chunks of text only after i go to the homescreen and return back into the app. however, it doesnt constantly update the textview, and sometimes hangs and crashes.

Comment: I've created a simple handler which can update the textview with plain text without problems, but then i faced major problems getting it to read the process :(

Comment: I have updated your question with that additional information and reformatted the code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an android expert but I notice that:

- you are running I/O operations in the UI thread - that will freeze your GUI until the I/O operation finishes ==> run them in a separate thread.
- you update the UI from outside the UI thread in `ListenThread`, which can lead to unexpected results

You can read more about it in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) (make sure you read the 2 examples as the first one is broken (on purpose)).

**EDIT**
In conclusion you should have something like this in your first piece of code:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now Capturing Packets", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {

                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                    ...
                    CaptureActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.CaptureText.setText("Active");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                ListenThread thread = new ListenThread(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)));
                thread.start();
            }
        }).start();
    }
});
```

and in the second:

```
   while (true) {
        try {
            CaptureActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.CaptureText.setText("exec");
                }
            });

            int a = 1;
            String received = reader.readLine();
            while (a == 1) {
                CaptureActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.LiveTraffic.append(received);
                        CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.LiveTraffic.append("\n");
                        CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.CaptureText.setText("in loop");
                    }
                });
                received = reader.readLine();
            }
            CaptureActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    CaptureActivity.this.thisActivity.CaptureText.setText("out loop");
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("FSE", "", e);
        }
    }
```

That should solve the specific UI interaction issue. But there are other logic problems in your code which go beyond this question (for example the fact that you never test if you have reached the end of the file you are reading, the fact that while(a==1) is an infinite loop because you never change the value of a etc.).

Comment: I've followed the tutorial, and while introducing it to my app it doesnt seem to work. which was expected :(

Comment: @ assylias. so from your answer suggestion, In laymen terms, how would I go about fixing my code? once again, please excuse my naivety. thanks

Comment: @user1488049 See my edit - disclaimer: I'm not an Android developer so there might be errors but I think it should be ok.